# Вывести числа от 0 до 99 ниже главной диагонали

Tags: c++

C++

[image: Вывести числа от 0 до 99 ниже главной диагонали.]

Никак до меня не доходит, прошу помощи.

Была попытка решить так, а также было множество других.
Только учусь, прошу строго не судить.

```
int main()
{
    int counter = 0, all = 10;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      for(; counter <= all; counter++) {
        if(counter == i) {
          break;
        }
        else {
          cout << counter << " ";
        }
      }
      all += 10;
      cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: @timob256, возможно, минусы поставили до того, как в вопрос был добавлен код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну пусть i отвечает за десятки, а j за единицы:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        if(j == i)
          break;
        else 
          cout << 10*(i-1)+j << " ";
      }
      cout << endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

https://ideone.com/WvkJHL

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  for (int q=0; q<10; ++q)
  {
    for (int w=0; ; ++w)
    {
      cout << (char)(q ? q+'0' : ' ') << (char)(w+'0');
      if (q == w) break;
      cout << ' ';
    }
    
    cout << endl;
  }
}
```

```
 0
10 11
20 21 22
30 31 32 33
40 41 42 43 44
50 51 52 53 54 55
60 61 62 63 64 65 66
70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88
90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99
```